# Does Ghostbane Dirge have a miss chance against incorporeal targets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, incorporeal

Ghostbane Dirge:

> The target coalesces into a semi-physical form for a short period of
>   time. While subject to the spell, the incorporeal creature takes half
>   damage (50%) from nonmagical attack forms, and full damage from magic
>   weapons, spells, spell-like effects, and supernatural effects.

Incorporeal (ex):

> Corporeal spells and effects that do not cause damage only have a 50%
>   chance of affecting an incorporeal creature.

As I understand is a spell cast by a corporeal caster a corporeal spell (with exceptions like force spells). Does that mean the Ghostbane Dirge spell only has a 50% Chance to affect the incorporeal target?

Seams odd to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*ghostbane dirge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghostbane-dirge/) spell does, in fact, typically have only a 50% chance of affecting the *only* creatures it *can* affect. A corporeal caster that casts *ghostbane dirge* is casting a spell "that do[es] not cause damage [so the spell has] only… a 50% chance of affecting an [incorporeal](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/universalMonsterRules.html) creature."

As written, I'm unsure what kind of a position a party would have to be in to make the spell *ghostbane dirge* a better choice than, for instance, the spell [*magic weapon*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon/) and just hitting Slimer twice as hard, but the *Advanced Player's Guide* [errata](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8fo1?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Players-Guide) changed only the spell's original saving throw from (embarrassingly) Fortitude (which made the spell useless against [undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead) creatures) to Will and the spell's unmentioned by the *Guide*'s [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn), leaving untouched the coin-toss failure chance.

The handful of readers that care deeply about this spell recommend a house rule saying that *The spell* ghostbane dirge *possesses the [descriptor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Descriptor-) force so that it can affect incorporeal creatures normally rather than the spell suffering the 50% miss chance when cast by a corporeal caster.*

Comment: The house rule seams reasonable to me. I would handle it that way to.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if *corporeal spell* = "spell cast by a corporeal creature" is a common thought process, though I can't find where that is coming from. I'm not finding anything or aware of anywhere that actually defines what a corporeal spell is;  however, if we look at what *corporeal* means

> having, consisting of, or relating to a physical material body.

To me that would mean a spell like [*Entangle*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/entangle/)  or [*Fireball*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) would be corporeal spells (regardless of caster) since they have corporeal manifestations (the plants wrapping around you or the flames exploding outward).

Reading it this way, I would say [*Ghostbane Dirge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghostbane-dirge/) doesn't really has a corporeal manifestation so wouldn't have the 50% miss chance. If you read [*Ghostbane Dirge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghostbane-dirge/) as being a corporeal spell, though, then yes it would have the miss chance.