# Can or can you not target an undead creature with the Atonement spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, undead, targeting

I have some undead PCs playing my game, and think it would be an interesting if they were given the option to atone instead of being outright destroyed if/when they run into a cleric of high enough level.

The [Atonement spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/atonement) clearly states that the target of the spell is: "living creature touched".

In the [Edimmu's](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/edimmu/) Rejuvenation section it says: "Upon an edimmu’s destruction, the magics that bind it to the mortal world linger on. Thus, 1d4+1 days after an edimmu’s destruction, the creature reforms with full hit points. The only way to destroy an edimmu is with an atonement spell. The atonement absolves the creature of its sins and sorrows, allowing it to finally return to its native plane."

In order to destroy an edimmu (CE Medium undead (incorporeal)), first you have to target it with an atonement spell, which, unless I'm misunderstanding something, isn't possible RAW.

Is this just an error, or is there a way to target an undead creature with the spell atonement that I haven't found?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Yeah. Rule 0 remains that the GM (you, it sounds like) makes decisions about how rules work and which are used, how, so long as the intent is to present a fun environment for you and your players

Comment: It's true, but I like to be consistent with RAW whenever possible.

Comment: @gatherer818 not all base undead are evil: e.g ghosts.  No creature with a head slot is ever always one alignment : the *helm of opposite alignment* exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Specific beats general

This is an actual application of specific beats general.  Some creatures have special notes in their entries about spells that have unusual effects on them.  Those spells have those effects on them, even though they normally don't do that.  For example; any undead creature can be restored to life via *true resurrection* unless its entry says otherwise-- that's part of the rules for the undead type-- even though *true resurrection* normally needs a soul that is free and willing to return.

The undead you mention is weird, in that it implicitly lets you target it with a spell it normally couldn't be targeted by and it is unclear if the spell's normal effects also apply.  Nevertheless, you *can* target it with atonement even though you *can't* target an ordinary vampire, e.g.

Note also that not being able to target invalid targets is not a thing in the rules but rather one of several popular ways of resolving the invalid target problem in Pathfinder.  Other options include you can target whatever but the spell will have no effect and you can target whatever but the spell has no effect but the slot (and spell for prepared casters) is not lost and can be cast again in the future.  Only if you actually straight-up *can't* target invalid targets-- which is a perfectly valid interpretation-- does this become an issue at all (in which case this creature should be ruled implicitly targetable as above).

Comment: So when this incorporeal creature temporarily dies it leaves remains that can be touched so as to satisfy the *atonement* spell?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I guess so? It says "Thus, 1d4+1 days after an edimmu’s destruction, the creature reforms with full hit points" -- I would probably have the incorporeal special quality's 50% failure rate  not apply to *atonement* castings on a dead edimmu's nonetheless incorporeal remains pre-rejuvenation.  Casting in combat would require a melee touch attack with 50% fail chance for corporeal sources (and also an hour so no one would do this I think). Really, though, were I to use the creature I would replace the casting of *atonement* with some other less confusing activity.

Comment: Another, less kind, GM might say, though, that the creature leaves no remains.  In that case the PCs can either camp and, one hour before it might rejuvenate for the next five days, begin casting *atonement*.  Alternatively, they could cough up some more gold and cast *Resurrection* or *True Resurrection* on the creature when it reappeared, or cast *dismissal* or otherwise kill it and finish the rest of the campaign before it respawns.

Answer (score 7):

#### It is neither an error nor dependent on another method.

RPGs use [exception-based rulesets](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62373/3548). That is, general rules are defined, and then other game elements will create specific exceptions to those rules as needed.

In this case, there is a general rule that Atonement can only target living creatures. The Edimmu, then, is a specific exception to that rule, as an undead creature whose rules clearly allow it to be targeted by Atonement (otherwise, how would its Rejuvenation ability even work). This doesn't negate the *general* rule that Atonement can't target undead, only the *specific* case of an Edimmu.

Answer (score 0):

A creature that possesses the type [undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/) cannot normally be targeted by the spell [*atonement*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/atonement/) because of the *atonement* spell's entry of *Target: Living creature touched* (also see [Aiming a Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Aiming_a_Spell) on Target or Targets). The supernatural ability **rejuvenation** of an [edimmu](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/edimmu/) presents an exception to the way the spell *atonement* normally works but *only* for a creature that possesses the rejuvenation ability. As also explained in fine answers [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161967/8610) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161966/8610), the game routinely makes specific exceptions to the general rules as part of its design.

This means that a cleric, druid, or inquisitor can't cast an *atonement* spell on your undead PCs unless that caster possesses a special ability that allows the caster to overcome the limitations of the *atonement* spell's *Target* entry.

That should answer the question. However, if you're interested in how difficult it is to send incorporeal undead genies to their final reward using the far-too-brief exception made by the rejuvenation ability then read on.

---

### A strict reading makes it extremely difficult to use [*atonement*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/atonement/) to send an [edimmu](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/edimmu/) to its native plane

The supernatural ability **rejuvenation** of the [edimmu](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/edimmu/)—an [incorporeal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Incorporeal_Subtype) and [undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Undead) genie—, in part,  says, "The only way to destroy an edimmu is with an [*atonement*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/atonement/) spell. The *atonement* absolves the creature of its sins and sorrows, allowing it to finally return to its native plane." Hence the edimmu's rejuvenation ability *does* create an exception for the *atonement* spell, but it's a far smaller exception than it may perhaps initially appear.

That is, even with the exception made by the edimmu's rejuvenation ability, a strict reading still doesn't change the *atonement* spell's entry of *Target: Living creature touched* as the rejuvenation ability makes no exception for the *atonement* spell's *Target* entry. Unless the less-strict reader extrapolates, speculates, or make house rules (a term I don't use pejoratively), exceptions change *only* what they *say* they change, and the only change to the *atonement* spell when an edimmu's (somehow) the subject is that the edimmu may opt to return to its native plane.

Thus it's the *atonement* spell's caster who is left with the uneasy task of somehow targeting with that *atonement* spell a creature *both* that possesses the type undead *and* that's probably destroyed. (And after these targeting obstacles there's the extraordinary ability [incorporeal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-Incorporeal-Ex-) and its 50% miss chance against corporeal effects.)

Nonetheless, the vast amount of material available for *Pathfinder* means that I have no doubt that a *specific* set of character options allows a caster to cast such an *atonement* spell. However, I suspect that set of character options won't be present in most campaigns (except, of course, in regions and settings overrun by edimmus).

Finally—and not inconsequentially—, the edimmu's original and (so far as I'm aware) only treeware appearance is in [*House of the Beast*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601251602) (2009), part 2 of the **Legacy of Fire** adventure path that Paizo published for *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5*, and *House* is for level 5 PCs that by the adventure's end achieve level 7. In other words, *it doesn't matter* that in the adventure where edimmus actually appear as antagonists that an edimmu can be returned to its native plane only with an *atonement* spell: the PCs that encounter them won't typically have access to *atonement* spells anyway. (The *atonement* spell is usually available only to characters level 9 and higher.)

What this all adds up to for this reader is the humble suggestion that perhaps the rejuvenation ability of the edimmu *is* actually an error… of sorts. I mean, the ability as it's presented *does*—if tilt your head and squint—function mechanically, but for an adventurer to reach the goal of that specific *atonement* spell requires leaping through *how many* flaming hoops exactly? Honestly, typical adventurers could very well find it easier to destroy forever a [lich](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/lich/) than to redeem and send home a bothersome edimmu! (And the typical edimmu is only CR 3!)

I suspect somebody involved with *House of the Beast*—likely somebody late at night on deadline—forgot (or forgot to care) that the spell *atonement* had that *Target: Living creature touched* entry. This wouldn't be the first time that Paizo seemed to fail to realize how abilities and exceptions to them work (for example, see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108909/8610) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61767/8610)) or that special care must be taken when designing effects for undead creatures (for example, see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102801/8610)).

In the end, a GM that wants to use edimmus in a traditional campaign may want to make a house rule like ***A creature can cast an* atonement *spell on the remains of a destroyed edimmu as if those remains were a corporeal living creature***, but the reader should be aware that this *is* a house rule. Another GM may see things differently, expecting characters who took specific options to thwart her campaign's edimmu invasion.

---

***Note:*** As an example, the spell-like ability second chance *that's the level 8 granted power of the inquisition [Redemption](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/inquisitions/inquistions-paizo/redemption-inquisition/) specifically does circumstantially overcome any targeting restrictions on the* atonement *spell that the spell-like ability largely emulates when the* second chance *ability says that "you can cast* atonement *as a spell-like ability, targeting a creature that has violated the tenets of a religion you both share or that freely desires to convert to your alignment." (An incorporeal miss chance continues to apply to the typical corporeal caster, though.) Still, because of the level at which it becomes available, even this special ability can't help PCs who are fighting their way through* House of the Beast, *but the* second chance *ability may be useful against your campaign's undead PCs.*